# Any ideas why submit button don't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5

Simple submit button form with 2 radio buttons.
   But I can't simply submit -submit button don't work.
   I am newbie in laravel and bootstrap. help me please?

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <form method="POST" class="form-inline" action="{{action('OrderController@submitOrder')}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
              <div class="btn-group " data-toggle="buttons">
               <label class="btn btn-default active">
                    <input type="radio" name="type" value="cash" checked> <i class="fa fa-btn fa-rub"></i>Деньги</label>
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input type="radio" name="type" value="card"> <i class="fa fa-btn fa-credit-card"></i>Карта</label>
                    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Отправить">
               </div>
       </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Open your developer tools console in your browser (typically `<F12>`) and check to see if you're receiving any errors. Also, right click on the form choose `Inspect Element` from the context menu and make sure the form `action` was parsed correctly. It appears, you're using the Blade templating engine that comes with Laravel. It's important to make sure that it is configured correctly and that the action is being parsed properly before the code is returning the view to the front end.

Comment: of course already did, when I'am deleting radio buttons - submit works fine, so action string is correct

Comment: If you take out submit button outside `<div>`, it might work. Now submit button is a part of toggle buttons. Do you mean to do that way?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `<input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Отправить">` try `<button class="btn btn-success" type='submit'> Отправить </button>`